# Async Storage Error Unhandled Promise Rejection in Switch

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native and now i have a problem.
I'm trying to save my data into local storage using Async Storage, I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_asyncstorage.htm) ,

it worked properly but not in my switch code.
This is my constructor

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)         
    this.state = {prevBtn: undefined}
    this.onPrevValueChange = this.onPrevValueChange.bind(this);
 }
```

then i get the item in my didMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.getQuestionnaire();
        AsyncStorage.getItem('prevBtn').then((value) => this.setState({ 'prevBtn': value }));
    }
```

set the value when it change:

```
onPrevValueChange = (value) =>  {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('prevBtn', value);
    this.setState({ prevBtn: value  });
}
```

and render method:

```
render(){
    const {}
    return(
        <Switch 
             value={prevBtn}
             backgroundActive={'red'}
             onValueChange={this.onPrevValueChange}  
        /> 
    );
}
```

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Have you tried doing () => this.onPrevValueChane() ? I'm not sure what your question is here?

Comment: yes, i switched it. But it return the error "Unhandled promise rejecte.d . . . "

Comment: Can you share an example code on snack.expo.io? I would like to help

Comment: here is my full code https://snack.expo.io/@labirin/carefree-salsa

Comment: Your code looks fine, for sanity check can you try react-native's Switch?

Comment: I suspect you're setting your AsyncValue to your boolean state somewhere.  The value you receive from AsyncStorage are type String, you'll have to convert them to boolean.

Answer (score 0):

issue with `setState` in `componentDidMount`, when you setting value for `prevBtn` using single quotation mark **`** so it is behaving like `String` not a `state`, use it as below:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.getQuestionnaire();
        AsyncStorage.getItem('prevBtn').then((value) => this.setState({ prevBtn: value }));
    }
```

In `render` you are using `prevBtn` directly, use it as `this.state.prevBtn`.

```
render(){
    const {}
    return(
        <Switch 
             value={this.state.prevBtn}
             backgroundActive={'red'}
             onValueChange={this.onPrevValueChange}  
        /> 
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your componentDidMount to this:

Note that `AsyncStorage.getItem` always returns a string, you'll have to convert it to a boolean before using it.  And as the other commenter pointed out, you can't have quotes around the state property.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getQuestionnaire();
  AsyncStorage.getItem('prevBtn').then((value) => {
    value === 'true' 
      ? this.setState({ prevBtn: true })
      : this.setState({ prevBtn: false })
  });
}
```